# Different figures in row and column using subfloat command

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfloats

I have written the following code to arrange three figures as you see in the picture below. Do you have any idea, how can I better arrange these figures? for some reasons there are lots of free space in the right and left of the pictures. If I replace `0.45\textwidth` by, for example, `0.5\textwidth`, then I will have three figures aligned in column!! BTW, I cannot use `\subfigure` command due to the clash between the packages. [image]
Many thanks

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,oneside,final]{book}

\usepackage{tikz,float,subfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mwe}
\newsavebox{\measurebox}

\begin{document}
%%%%%
%%%%%
\begin{figure}
\centering
\sbox{\measurebox}{%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
  \subfloat[]
    {
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}[
  width=\textwidth,
]
\addplot[solid,smooth,mark=none,color={rgb,255:red,0; green,0; blue,255}]
coordinates {(9.8,0) (10.1,0.25)
         (10.4,0.5) (10.7,0.75) (11,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    }
  \end{minipage}}
\usebox{\measurebox}
\begin{minipage}[b][\ht\measurebox][s]{0.45\columnwidth}
\centering
\subfloat[]
  {
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
   \begin{axis}[
   width=0.5\textwidth,
   ]
\addplot[solid,smooth,mark=none,color={rgb,255:red,0; green,0; blue,255}]
coordinates {(-180,0) (-90,0.25)
         (0,0.5) (90,0.75) (180,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
  \label{fig:Ex02_FT_fields}
  }

\vfill

\subfloat[]
  {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth,height=2cm]{{example-image-a}}\label{fig:figC}}
\end{minipage}
\caption{my caption. (a) is .... (b) is .... (c) is ....}
\label{fig:Test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please extend your code snippet to complete small document (beginning with `\documentclass`, ending with `\end{document}` and containing all data that code of figures can be compiled) with your figure. from your code fragment we can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Zarko yes, I edited my code.

Comment: unfortunately your mwe (minimal working example) doesn't work. it also is not minimal. please remove from preamble all packages and your definitions not needed for showing your mages.

Comment: I modified it again and made the code minimal. Tested in a different directory on my computer and  It works now.

Comment: meanwhile i already wrote my answer :-), where i made own minimal version of your code. see if it help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess that you like to obtain something like this:

[image]

above result i obtain by the following MWE (Minimal Working Example):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,oneside,final]{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{figure}[htb]
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.60\textwidth}
  \subfloat[]
    {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  width=\linewidth,
  line width=1pt,
  ymin=0, ymax=1,
  xmin=9.8, xmax=11,
  xlabel=Frquency (GHz),
  ylabel=$\left|S_{64}\right|$,
            ]
\addplot[mark=none] coordinates {(9.8,0) (10.1,0.25)
                                 (10.4,0.5) (10.7,0.75) (11,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    }
  \end{minipage}\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.35\columnwidth}
    \centering
\subfloat[]
  {
  \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[
   width=\linewidth,
   line width=1pt,
   ymin=0, ymax=1,
   xmin=-180, xmax=180,
   xlabel=$\theta\,\left(\text{degree}\right)$,
   ylabel=$\text{FT}\left( H_z\right)$,
   ]
\addplot[mark=none] coordinates {(-180,0) (-90,0.25)
                                 (0,0.5) (90,0.75) (180,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \label{fig:Ex02_FT_fields}
  }

\subfloat[]
  {
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=2cm,keepaspectratio]{figures/temp_disp}
    \label{fig:figC}
  }
\end{minipage}
    \caption{my caption. (a) is .... (b) is .... (c) is ....}
    \label{fig:Test}
    \end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

as you can see, i remove all packages and your definitions, which are not relevant to your problem. i must confess that i not understand your way to including image in figure. it seems that use of `savingbox` is source of your problem. remove them and correct definition of width of images form `width=\textwidth` to `\linewidth` can do job better.

I also not figure out proportion of width of mini pages. you can change as you wish.

Comment: Yes, this works now — many thanks. The reason I didn't initially remove the packages and definitions in the preamble was to let people know what I have there, which is part of a very big document. And also to let them know that I cannot remove them!!:)), as other parts of my document may give an error. Anyways, now your code works. And you are right, the problem was savingbox